# R: using ddply with a function

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to use the "ddply" function in conjunction with the "summarize" function, but I'm having difficulty.

Below is an extract of my code:

```
  orderSubsConsolidate = ddply(merged, .(RIC,leg),summarize,fill.Quant = sum(fill.Quant),
                 fill.Price = function(merged){sum(merged[,7]*merged[,8])/sum(merged[,7})
```

"merged" is the matrix containing the information that I would like to summarize. I am summarizing by columns "RIC" and "leg". The problem I am having is applying a function to the fill.Price column.

This is an extract from the "merged" matrix:

> ```
> Trade      RIC    leg Basket.Name Status  Order.Msg   fill.Quant  fill.Price
>   ATNATNP ATNJ.J  1   ATNATNP1a1  Filled               100           200       
>   ATNATNP ATNPp.J 2   ATNATNP2a1  Filled               100           200       
>   ATNATNP ATNJ.J  1   ATNATNP1b1                       300           400
> ```

Essentially, what the code above is trying to do is aggregate the fill.Quant column by RIC and leg, and then populate the corresponding fill.Price column with [(fill.Price*fill.Quant)/fill.Quant], resulting in a matrix as given below:

> ```
> RIC      leg  fill.Quant  fill.Price
> ATNJ.J    1      400            350
> ATNPp.J   2      100            350
> ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Thanks!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use an anonymous function:

```
ddply(merged, .(RIC,leg), function(x) 
                           data.frame( fill.Quant = sum(x$fill.Quant), 
                                       fill.Price = sum(x[,7]*x[,8])/sum(x[,7])))
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it should be

```
orderSubsConsolidate = ddply(merged, .(RIC,leg), summarize,
                       fill.Quant = sum(fill.Quant),
                       fill.Price = weighted.mean(fill.Price, fill.Quant))
```

Comment: +1 for using `summarize` but above all, replacing these ugly and non-robust indices (`7` and `8`) by their variables names. That should have been the accepted answer IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

another solution, which gives you code which is IMHO easily readable and reusable you could do:

```
foo <- function(quant, price){
  sum( quant*price ) / sum(price)
}

ubsConsolidate <- ddply( merged, .(RIC,leg), summarize,
  fill.Quant = sum( fill.Quant ),
  fill.Price = foo( fill.Quant, fill.Price )
)
```

Comment: not much different than @Stephen's... It even has the same mistake I have fixed in his: you are not doing a true weighted mean, you need to divide by `sum(price)`.

Comment: @flodel, True and thanks for pointing the mistake. Nevertheless, the question was rather how to use a self written (maybe anonymous) function together with `ddply` and `summarise`. That the particular function reduces to `weighted.mean` which is already implemented is a different story.